# Custom compass calibration view like Compass app has

Tags: iphone, ios, core-location, magnetometer

[image]

I want to make compass like native compass app has with such calibration view.
This method tell you that need to calibrate your hardware    `- (BOOL)locationManagerShouldDisplayHeadingCalibration:(CLLocationManager *)manager`  
But how to get notification that calibration complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can monitor the `headingAccuracy` of subsequent location updates to see if your accuracy did increase. This is what Apple has to say:

> The alert remains visible until calibration is complete or until you explicitly dismiss it by calling the dismissHeadingCalibrationDisplay method. In the latter case, you can use this method to set up a timer and dismiss the interface after a specified amount of time has elapsed.

So setting up a timer and dismissing it if accurac increased should work for you?